# If $T$ has an adjoint, why is $T(X\times Y)\simeq T(X)\times T(Y)$?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are categories with products, and $T$ a functor between them. If $X$ and $Y$ are objects in $\mathcal{A}$, then we have a natural morphism $f\colon T(X\times Y)\to T(X)\times T(Y)$ as follows.

In $\mathcal{A}$, we have the product $X\times Y$, with corresponding morphisms $\pi_1:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_2:X\times Y\to Y.$ Under $T$, we get a diagram of objects in $\mathcal{B}$ of morphisms $T(\pi_1):T(X\times Y)\to T(X)$ and $T(\pi_2):T(X\times Y)\to T(Y)$. Since products exist in $\mathcal{B}$, we have a product $(T(X)\times T(Y),p_1,p_2)$ such that there is a unique morphism $f\colon T(X\times Y)\to T(X)\times T(Y)$ such that $p_1f=T(\pi_1)$ and $p_2f=T(\pi_2)$.

If $T$ has a left adjoint $G$, how does this in fact imply $f$ is an isomorphism? I considered the natural bijection of hom spaces

$$
\varphi\colon\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{B}(T(X\times Y),T(X)\times T(Y))\simeq\operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{A}(X\times Y,G(T(X)\times T(Y)))
$$

Then for $f$ in the LHS, there is a corresponding right adjunct 
$$
\varphi f=\operatorname{rad}f\colon X\times Y\to G(T(X)\times T(Y)).$$ Is there a way to tweak this to conclude $f$ is invertible?

Comment: Show that $T(X\times Y)$ has the universal property of a product.

Comment: Right adjoints preserve arbitrary limits. The proof can be done in one line.

Comment: You start well Camilla, but you do not use the *bonus* universal arrows (unit and counit) that come with the adjunction. Stefan does that in his answer. Please note that your $\varphi$ is normally described as $\varphi^{-1}$ in the literature (you wrote the isomorphism in the opposite direction to the standard one). Please see CWM or Awodey. So your $\operatorname{rad}f$ is actually called a *left adjunct* $\operatorname{lad}f$ in the literature.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $f_i:B\to T(A_i),\ i=1,2$ are two arrows in $\mathcal B$. Then you have unique $f'_i:SB→A_i$ in $\mathcal A$ such that $Tf'_i∘η_B=f_i$. These induce an arrow $f':SB→A_1×A_2$ with $\pi_i∘f'=f'_i$. This one corresponds by the natural isomorphism to the composition 
$$Tf'∘η_B:B→T(A_1×A_2)$$
We check that $Tπ_i∘Tf'∘η_B=Tf'_i∘η_B=f_i$. So it remains to show that this arrow is the only one. To do this, assume that $g:B→T(A_1×A_2)$ is another such arrow, and show that the corresponding $g':SB→A_1×A_2$ must be the same as $f'$.

This shows that $T(A_1×A_2)$ has the universal property of a product with projections $Tπ_i$, so $T$ preserves the product. Note that it is not necessary to requite $\mathcal B$ to have products.

The proof for the more general fact that right adjoints preserve all limits will look very similar.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. What is $\eta_B$?

Comment: It the unit of the adjunction. Do you know the characterization via unit? The isomorphism $\mathcal A(SB,A)\simeq\mathcal B(B,TA)$ (when $B$ is fixed and $A$ is the variable) is determined by an arrow $η_B:B→TSB$. If you have an arrow $g:SB→A$, then it is mapped to the arrow $Tg∘η_B:B→TSB→TA$. This is called the unit and exists for each $B\in\cal B$.